# Creation of a DBA.SE-flavored Minimal, Complete, and Viable Example page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

All too often I see questions that are vague and just outright difficult to understand.  I try to send the OPs to Stack Overflow's [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page, but that doesn't seem to work often enough and I wonder if we need to create a dba-flavored MCVE page on our help site.

I would envision something similar to SO's page, but modified with a DBA audience in mind.  So maybe something similar to the following (and edits are more than welcome here):

> **Note:** This page is derived from the **MCVE** help page found at
>   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
>
> **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**
>
> When asking a question about a problem within your database solution,
>   you will get much better answers if you provide data and code people
>   can use to reproduce the problem. That data and code should be…
>
> - …Minimal – Use as little data and code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - …Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem, including basic table structure, troublesome queries, and
>     execution/explain plans
> - …Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem
>
> **Minimal**
>
> The more code or data there is to go through, the less likely people
>   can find your problem. Streamline your example in one of two ways:
>
> 1. **Restart from scratch.** Create a new database model, adding only the data that is needed to see the problem. This can be faster for
>      vast systems where you think you already know the source of the
>      problem. Also useful if you can't post the original table
>      structure/data publicly for legal or ethical reasons.  You can even
>      use an online resource such as [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or
>      [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) both of which support most major
>      RDBMS platforms.
> 2. **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of data or code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start
>      removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add
>      the last part back.  Not only can this help you identify the problem
>      is with your code or with the data, but allows you to include that in
>      your question for others to review.
>
> **Minimal *and* readable**
>
> Minimal does not mean *terse* – don't sacrifice communication to
>   brevity. Use consistent naming and formatting, and include comments if
>   needed to explain portions of the code or the table structures you're
>   defining.
>
> **Complete**
>
> Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is
>   included:
>
> - Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post.  Again if this is even
>     easier if you build your MCVE in either
>     [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or [SQL
>     Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) which allow others to run your
>     solution.
> - The problem might not be in the part you suspect it is, but another part entirely.
>
> If the problem requires external objects from a database, include them
>   if possible or at least a description of what is needed.
>
> **Verifiable**
>
> To help you solve your problem, others will need to verify that it
>   exists:
>
> - **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what
>     the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is
>     producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your
>     question.
> - **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** If your question isn’t about a syntax error, ensure that it can run
>     without being modified.
> - **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't
>     test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to
>     help.
>
> You may have been told to include an MCVE by some helpful commentary,
>   or perhaps even an MVCE if they were rushed; sorry for the
>   initialisms, this is what they were referring to.